# Unable to connect to a url with python request module

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm unable to connect to the URL using requests module, but it works fine when browsed in a browser. Could it be some robots.txt issue `Allowed/Disallowed` issue ?

Below is the codebase.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://myntra.com')

print(r)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Pass a user agent argument and it should respond, the site doesn't like bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some websites block access from non-web browser ‘User-Agents’ to prevent web scraping, including from the default Python’s requests ‘User-Agent’.

so you need to pass a user agent as like a web browser, for example:

```
r = requests.get('https://myntra.com/', headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0",
    },)
```

The ‘User-Agent’ string contains information about which browser is being used, what version and on which operating system.

Comment: This works perfectly well.. However, I anticipated this..and also tried adding headers to it.. But it didnt work for the headers that I used.. Sharing the headers that I used.. ```'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'```Could you pls confirm the exact issue in my headers.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast in that user agent the Chrome version is really old `Chrome/39.0.2171.95` and the website block access HTTPS due to security issues, probably.if you remove that it should work , you probably need to check the webkit version as well

Answer (score 0):

The URL shown in the question requires that a User-Agent is passed with the GET request.

```
import requests
AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'
headers = {'User-Agent': AGENT}
(r := requests.get('https://myntra.com', headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
```